# List of DateTimeField in Django model

Tags: django

I have a Subject model, and every subject needs a schedule, so I want to have a list of datetimes in the model. I know that postgres has a ArrayField method but I'm using SQLite3.

```py
class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    schedule = #Here I need the list of datetimes
```

It's a short question but I didn't find anything like this

Answer (score 1):

You can't put something like a `ListField` inside an SQLite3 model. But you can by using foreign keys and another model:

```py
class Schedule():
    subject=models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data=...
```

And

```py
all_schdules=subject.schdule_set.all()
```